# custom form submit in a new browser tab

Tags: forms, 6

I have a custom form in Drupal 6 and every thing works perfectly except I want the form submit to open in new window. 
I tried using the following code as per form api for drupal 6 but it does not work

```
$form['save_and_print'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Save and Print'),
          '#attributes' => array('target' => '_blank'), // this does not work
);
```

Was anyone able to achieve this? Please help!

Answer (score 8):

You have to set the `target` attribute in the form tag itself:

```
$form['#attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
```

Put this code somewhere in your form function.

**Update:**

To get this functionality to a particular button, you have to be tricky.

```
$form['save_and_print'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Save and Print'),
      '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'this.form.target="_blank";return true;'),
);
```

When clicked, this will set the parent form element's `target` attribute to `_blank` which opens in a new tab when pressed. 
If you clicked the button once and when you click some other button in the same form, it will open in a new tab as well because the previous `onclick` event set the `target` attribute to `_blank`.

To workaround, you have to set this onclick event to ALL submits.

**To submit the form in same page/tab:**

```
$form['save'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Save'),
      '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'this.form.target="_self";return true;'),
);
```

**To submit in a new tab:**

```
$form['save_and_print'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Save and Print'),
      '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'this.form.target="_blank";return true;'),
);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wx3cn/1/)

Comment: thanks for your time! :) 
But that will be applicable for all submits in that form. I wanted it work for selected ones. :(

Comment: You'll have to go for javascript then.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: Working like a charm!