# .attr('target','_blank'); does not work

Tags: forms, javascript, chaos-tool-suite

I have a custom module with differents forms and on one of these forms i want to submit and open the result on a new tab. 
I found a way to do this on this link : [custom form submit in a new browser tab](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62577/custom-form-submit-in-a-new-browser-tab)

it works great but instead i need to make a js file to do the same thing.

If it works with  the target attributes (link above) directly put in my form why make the same thing in a js file ? i suppose that i will have to use a js file,  because with the target attributes it does not work, a new tab does not open when i clicked on a modal button (using ctools modal form).

So my problem is the following: when i make a js file and put this code

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.multi_example = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('#pv-button').attr('target', '_blank');
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

It does anything ! 
On my js file, my id button works properly, i have tested it with a simple alert:

```
.click(function(){
            alert("Hello World");
}
```

and it works. I've also tested with `window.open('','_blank')` and a new tab open. So i think there is a problem with the .attr() function. I've passed a long time to search a solution on "google" but nothing... i need some help please.

PS: I want to precise that i have used all these codes (code above) on a normal node, not on a modal.

I'm using Drupal 7.50, jQuery 1.10.2, PHP 5.6.19

Answer (score 1):

This questions seems unrelated to Drupal, and is probably more appropriate on a different forum.

I'm no expert on HTML, but you should make sure that:

(a) you are applying the `target` attribute to html tags that **accept it** (basically `<a>` and `<form>` only). Notice that  submit `<button>` or `<input type='submit'>` has a different attribute called `formtarget` (rather than `target`)

And (b) if you are applying this to an `<a>` tag, it has to also have an `href` attribute. See [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

The link you posted for a "custom submit in a new browser tab" answer probably adds the `target` attribute to the `<form>` tag, not to the input.