# How can I add a "target" attribute to a custom form?

Tags: 8, forms

I've made a custom form in a module in Drupal 8, but I'd like to add target="_blank" in the form tag. When I try to add it in `$form['#attributes']['target']`, the attribute is shown in the wrapper of the form and not in the form tag itself.

Does anyone have an idea where this could be done?

Comment: If you want to directly control which element in HTML the attribute ends up on, you may need to turn to [Twig](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/working-with-twig-templates). But, I have a feeling your use case probably matches one of those given in [AyeshK's answer to #62577](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/62578/82623) and highly recommend you implement something from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [custom form submit in a new browser tab](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62577/custom-form-submit-in-a-new-browser-tab)

Comment: Thx @IsaiahNixon. adding  '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'this.form.target="_blank";return true;'),' to the submit button did the trick for me.